# Run jQuery on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery that runs as a user types in an input box.

```js
var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
  }).hide();
});
```

How do I get the same jQuery to run if there's already text in the input box on page load?

Comment: Move the function out of the `keyup` callback into its own named function. Passed that named function to `keyup` and call it again on initialization. Functions are specifically used to run a procedure upon calling them.

Answer (score 4):

Just move all the logic into its own named function:

```js
function doFilter() {
  var $input = $('#search'),
    val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($input.val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

  $('#table tbody tr').show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
  }).hide();
}

$(function() {
  $('#search').on('keyup', doFilter); // Add it as a listener

  doFilter(); // Call it upon initialization
});
```

Comment: We can also call that method inside `ready`.

Comment: This [is a shortcut](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for `$.ready`: `$(function() { /* ... */ })`

Comment: If you like shortcuts then you can also use `$(() => { })`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ready` function and check if textbox has text in it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("#search").val() !== "") {
    // your code here.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You *should* move the logic into its own function but you can just trigger the keyup event if you don't want to refactor what you have.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    //your existing code
    console.log($(this).val());
  }).trigger("keyup");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" value="abc" />
```